# Flutter imagepicker.pickvideo return jpg

Tags: flutter, dart, video, imagepicker

I'm using this to return the video file but I got .jpg

```
Future<File> getVideo() async {
     var video = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(
          source: ImageSource.gallery);
      return video;
    }
```

I want to `ImagePicker.pickVideo()` return video file instead of .jpg file so I can upload this file to firebase, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using the package:
https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

**pickVideo()** method has been decrecated, and you will need to replace these apis with **getVideo()**

As explained the repositories' documentation:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/image_picker/image_picker

Write this:

```
final _picker = ImagePicker();
PickedFile video = await _picker.getVideo(...)
```

However I would suggest to use this package as an alternative:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_document_picker

This package will allow you to select all videos on the device, including those taken from a users' Google Drive or iCloud providers. In this case write this:

```
FlutterDocumentPickerParams params = FlutterDocumentPickerParams(
      allowedUtiTypes: [
        'public.video',
        'public.mpeg',
        'public.mpeg-4-audio',
        'com.apple.protected-​mpeg-4-audio'
      ],
      allowedMimeTypes: [
        'video/mpeg',
        'video/x-flv',
        'video/mp4',
        'application/x-mpegURL',
        'video/quicktime',
        'video/x-msvideo',
        'video/x-ms-wmv',
        'video/ogg',
        'video/mp2t',
        'video/3gpp'
      ],
      invalidFileNameSymbols: ['/'],
    );

    return await FlutterDocumentPicker.openDocument(params: params);
```

You will need to make sure that the Mimes and Uti types for videos on iOS & Android are set correctly.

Comment: i tried, but when i convert it to file it still returns jpg

Comment: try the other package I suggested then

Comment: Just try it for now, and if it works for you it's a temporary workaround

Comment: can you check the result by the way of the returned file. So try to get the path of the resulting video file, and print(). Check to see if the file returned from the package image_picker is correct (as in it's a video file and not an image file), or it's your own code. Usually it's a bug in your code.

Comment: thank you for advising to use getVideo.. and functionally it works, but i got confused a few seconds because it returns jpg file but when i saw this file in firebase it recognized as a video.. im just curios why it names has include 'jpg' so i thought it was it's extension